# pHow can I reposition the axes of a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting

I'd like to reposition the axes in my plot of a surface. Please consider the following code:

```
Z[t_, α_] = t^3*α; 
Plot3D[Z[t, α], {t, 0, 2}, {α, 0.5, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "α", "Z"}]
```

I want to chenge the Axes `Z` with `α`, `t` with `Z`  and `α` with `t`.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried writing the AxesLabel in the correct order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Z[t_, α_] = t^3*α;
```

Using [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html)

```
Plot3D[α /. Solve[z == Z[t, α], α][[1]],
 {z, 0, 8}, {t, 0, 2},
 PlotRange -> {0.5, 1},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"z", "t", "α"}),
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Or using [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Z[t, α], t, α},
 {t, 0, 2}, {α, 0.5, 1},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"z", "t", "α"}),
 BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or using [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html)

```
ContourPlot3D[z == Z[t, α],
 {z, 0, 8}, {t, 0, 2}, {α, 0.5, 1},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"z", "t", "α"}),
 BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}]
```

Comment: For labels to not overlap with numbers you may add `Framed`: `AxesLabel -> (Framed[Style[#, 14, Bold], FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 5]` or other appropriate margins values.